Conflict problem with order completion in Theme Journal OpenCart
        public function index()
    {
        $this->load->language('extension/payment/moyasar3');
        $this->load->model('extension/payment/moyasar3');
        $this->load->model('checkout/order');

        $order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);

        $amount = $this->currency->format(
            $order_info['total'],
            $order_info['currency_code'],
            $order_info['currency_value'],
            false
        );

        $amount *= 100;

        $invoice = [
            'amount' => round($amount),
            'description' => 'Order id #' . $this->session->data['order_id'],
            'currency' => $order_info['currency_code'],
            'success_url' => $this->url->link('extension/payment/moyasar3/callback', '', true),
            'back_url' => $this->url->link('checkout/cart'),
            'metadata' => [
                'order_id' => $this->session->data['order_id'],
                'firstname' => $order_info['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $order_info['lastname'],
                'telephone' => $order_info['telephone'],
                'email' => $order_info['email'],
                'shipping_address_1' => $order_info['shipping_address_1'],
                'shipping_address_2' => $order_info['shipping_address_2'],
                'shipping_city' => $order_info['shipping_city'],
                'shipping_zone' => $order_info['shipping_zone'],
                'shipping_postcode' => $order_info['shipping_postcode'],
                'orderdate' => $order_info['date_added']
            ]
        ];

        try {
            $response = (new QuickHttp)
                ->basic_auth($this->config->get('payment_moyasar3_api_secret_key'))
                ->post('https://api.moyasar.com/v1/invoices', $invoice)
                ->json();
        } catch (QuickHttpException $error) {
            $message = 'Could not created invoice, un-expected error';

            if ($error->response->isJson()) {
                $body = $error->response->json();
                $message = $body['message'];
            }

            $this->log->write('Could not create invoice for order ' . $this->session->data['order_id']);
            $this->log->write("Server returned with $message");
            $this->log->write('Server status' . $error->response->status());

            echo '<b>' . $message . '</b>';
            die;
        }
 
        $url = preg_replace('?lang=en', '', $response['url']);

        ?>
            <script>
                window.location.href = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
            </script>
        <?php

        die;
    }


The problem is in the part
**
$url = preg_replace('?lang=en', '', $response['url']);
    ?>
        <script>
            window.location.href = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
        </script>

**
When you go to complete the order, you will be automatically transferred to the payment site before completing the required fields - name, address, etc.
I tried to add it
**
return $this->load->view('extension/payment/moyasar3', $data);
**
But unfortunately the same problem
